# Clear Button UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view that has a UITextView and I need to add a clear button. However, I cannot wrap my  head around it. I tried multiple approaches but none seemed to work. I need to know what I should write inside the button in order to clear the text of TextInputview

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```swift
struct Input: View {
    @State var content: String
    var hint: String = ""
    @State private var style: Input.Style = .idle
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TextInputView(text: content, desiredHeight: self.$desiredHeight, hasContent: $hasContent)
                    .focused($isFocused)
                    .onChange(of: isFocused) { isFocused in
                        withAnimation {
                            style = isFocused ? .focused : .idle
                        }
                    }
            }
            Button {
                // I need to know what to insert here
            } label: {
                Text("Press Me")
            }   .hidden(!(hasContent && isFocused))
                .padding(.trailing, Constants.paddingHorizontal)    
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TextInputView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @State var text: String
    var foregroundColor: Color = .grey

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextInputView>) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.font = font.uiFont
        view.textColor = .init(foregroundColor)
        view.isEditable = true
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextInputView>) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.textColor = .init(foregroundColor)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text, parent: self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        @Binding var parent: TextInputView
        init(text: Binding<String>, parent: TextInputView) {
            _text = text
            _parent = .constant(parent)
        }

        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            text = textView.text
        }
        
        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to just to `self.content = ""`; I tried to use dispatch queues, I tried to trigger a `onpreferencesChange`.

Some solutions suggest outlets but I can't figure out how to use them and failed every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the input `String` is defined twice as `@State`. It should be marked as`@Binding` in `TextInputView`. This way the value is linked between the two views and change in one (i.e. `Input`) is reflected in the other (i.e. `TextInputView`). That's how it would look simplified:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var content: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextInputView(text: $content)
            Button {
                content = ""
            } label: {
                Text("Press Me")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextInputView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextInputView>) -> UITextView {
        // etc. ...
```